# Old version of websites showing with Azure

Tags: azure, dns

I'm running into an issue where different versions of the site are showing up but it only seems to happen based on the URL you type in the address bar.

http://example.com -- shows correct version
http://www.example.com -- shows correct version
www.example.com -- shows old/wrong version

Thanks for any help in advance! It's becoming a nuisance and I can't tell if it's a DNS issue, or something wrong within the Azure web app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by doing a couple things

First I had to add a `CNAME` record for `www` pointing to `azuresitename.domain.com`

Next I had to delete the bad folder out of `/wwwroot/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced`

After that, it was no longer showing the old/original version of the files.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a DNS issue.

Are you using a third party service for your domain name? If that's the case, you likely haven't verified the "www" part with them.

[Take a look at the guide here.](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/890336/Set-Your-GoDaddy-Domain-Name-To-Your-Azure-Website) You want to make sure that you have **everything** available:

Http
www
*